# How to save an image using JFileChooser

Tags: java, image, swing, serialization, jfilechooser

**Background info:** I've made a program that uploads an image using JFileChooser and have made fill in the space of the JFrame.

**My Question:** I've attempted implementing my method on a save button and so far I can pull up the JFileChooser but it will not actually save the image. So how would I go about saving the same image I previously uploaded using JFileChooser? I've seen many examples but don't really understand them.

**My browse img code:**

```
// When button pressed, allows user to browse inventory
BrowseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
        file.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        // Filter files
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg",
                "png");
        file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        int res = file.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selFile = file.getSelectedFile();
            String path = selFile.getAbsolutePath();
            label.setIcon(resize(path));
        } // End if
    } // End actionPerformer
}); // End ActionListener
```

**My save img code:**

```
// Save file
saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.png", "png"));
            if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String img = file.getAbsolutePath();
            } // End if
        } // End actionPerformed
    }); // End ActionListener
```

**Updated save img code:**

```
    // Save getFile
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser saveFile = new JFileChooser();
            saveFile.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            // Filter files
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".Images", "jpg", "png");
            saveFile.addChoosableFileFilter(filter2);
            int f1 = saveFile.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(f1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = saveFile.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(selFile, "png", file);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } // End if
            } // End actionPerformed
        }); // End ActionListener
```

Comment: Forget the file chooser for second, you're first problem should be to figure out how to save the image, as the file chooser just provides the means to change the location

Comment: I would recommend you start with [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [Writing/Saving an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Comment: If you make variable selFile global then ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(selFile),"png",file);  [read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) and [write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,java.lang.String,java.io.File))

Comment: @Syncit So I got that it gives no error until I actually try to save the image. The error is "image == null!". Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this because it is not actually catching the image I uploaded to the frame? I added my updated code.

Comment: in your browse image code the image which you have selected is stored in an variable called File selFile. I meant you should make that a global variable so read method can read the image from that browsed file and write it back to an different file. Don't declare an variable selFile of type BufferedImage. Either that or this variable must store whatever image is inside your label since you typed label.setIcon(resize(path))

Comment: @Syncit Sorry, I forgot to post the correct answer but here it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedImage getImg;
private String path1;  
private final JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");  

saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser getFile = new JFileChooser();
            getFile.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            // Filter files
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter1 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg",
                    "png");
            getFile.addChoosableFileFilter(filter1);
            int res = getFile.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selFile1 = getFile.getSelectedFile();
                path1 = selFile1.getAbsolutePath();
                label.setIcon(resize(path1));
                System.out.println("1st selFile1 = " + selFile1);                    
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(getImg, "jpg", selFile1);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            } // End if
        } // End actionPerformer
    }); // End ActionListener
```